# Getting test results easier in Jenkins

Tags: grails, jenkins

When I run grails tests via jenkins I can check the console to see everything passed.
I'll see something like this:

```
Tests PASSED - view reports in /Users/me/developer/gradlemucks/grails_2/hello-world/target/test-reports
```

Is there anyway I could put in a hyperlink somewhere in Jenkins to the test reports so that I could just click thru to the report? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [testing guide](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html), Grails outputs both `.html` and `.xml` formatted results from the tests by default. You can configure Jenkins to read the `.xml` files:

1. Install the JUnit or [xUnit](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) plugin.
2. Add a `Post-build Action` to `Publish JUnit test result report`.
3. Set `Test report XMLs` path to `build/test-results/*.xml` (or whatever path your JUnit .xml output files are dumped to).

This will permit you to click through the tests run for any build from the left sidebar within Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Side Bar Link Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sidebar-Link+Plugin)?  It allows you to add arbitrary links to the left side menu of a job.